# How to set a colored background to a frame?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to add a background color such as red or blue, etc... I tried almost everything I found on other forum posts, nothing worked.

*This is not my code. I took it from an open source and I am modifying it*

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.color.*;


public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Program program = new Program();
        program.run();
    }
}

class Program {
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private DrawPanel drawPanel;
    private java.util.List<Ball> balls;

    private int windowWidth = 640;
    private int windowHeight = 480;
    private String windowLabel = "Bounce Program";

    void run() {

        balls = new ArrayList<>();

        /* Generate balls */
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            Ball ball = new Ball(
                    /* Random positions from 0 to windowWidth or windowHeight */
                    (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * windowWidth),
                    (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * windowHeight),
                    /* Random size from 10 to 30 */
                    (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 10,
                    /* Random RGB colors*/
                    new Color(
                            (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 256)),
                            (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 256)),
                            (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 256))
                    ),
                    /* Random velocities from -5 to 5 */
                    (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) - 5),
                    (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) - 5)
            );

            balls.add(ball);
        }

        /* Initialize program */
        mainFrame = new JFrame();
        drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(drawPanel);
        mainFrame.setTitle(windowLabel);
        mainFrame.setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



        while (true) {
            for (Ball b: balls) {
                b.update();
            }

            /* Give Swing 10 milliseconds to see the update! */
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mainFrame.repaint();
        }
    }

    class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
            super.paintComponent(graphics);

            for (Ball b: balls) {
                b.draw(graphics);
            }

        }
    }

    class Ball {
        private int posX, posY, size;
        private Color color;

        private int vx = 5;
        private int vy = 5;

        public Ball(int posX, int posY, int size, Color color, int vx, int vy) {
            this.posX = posX;
            this.posY = posY;
            this.size = size;
            this.color = color;
            this.vx = vx;
            this.vy = vy;
        }

        void update() {

            if (posX > mainFrame.getWidth() || posX < 0) {
                vx *= -1;
            }

            if (posY > mainFrame.getHeight() || posY < 0) {
                vy *= -1;
            }

            if (posX > mainFrame.getWidth()) {
                posX = mainFrame.getWidth();
            }

            if (posX < 0) {
                posX = 0;
            }

            if (posY > mainFrame.getHeight()) {
                posY = mainFrame.getHeight();
            }

            if (posY < 0) {
                posY = 0;
            }

            this.posX += vx;
            this.posY += vy;

        }

        void draw(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillOval(posX, posY, size, size);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! So, can you elaborate more on what have you tried and how did it not work?

Comment: I think you should first learn the basics of using JFrame before looking at open source code and trying to change it. That way you can at least understand what you are doing and what the code is doing as well.

Comment: just call `mainframe.setBackground(Color.RED); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
```

You add a panel to the frame so you need to set the background of that panel:

```
drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
drawPanel.setBackground( Color.RED );
```